# Should namelists be avoided in Fortran and if so what is the recommended alternative?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I often use the namelist feature for flexible input of parameter lists to FORTRAN programmes, but the other day when searching to remind myself of their use I [came across this statement](https://www.adt.unipd.it/corsi/Bianco/www.pcc.qub.ac.uk/tec/courses/f77tof90/stu-notes/f90studentMIF_7.html):

> It (namelist language extension to f77) has now been included in the Fortran 90 language. However, NAMELIST is a poorly designed feature and should be avoided whenever possible.

I was just wondering

1. if this is a generally held view?
2. if yes, why is this the case?
3. what the suggested alternative is for parameter input? (I of course use netcdf for gridded data file input, I'm thinking of run-time parameter settings here).

Comment: Sorry, this is very opinion based. Many projects in meteorology (weather foracesting and climate models) use namelists for most of their configurations. Other people don't like them.

Comment: Also, the resource you link is very old, if it speaks just about Fortran 90, which is more than 25 years old. Namelists are certainly used in many projects as of 2017.

Comment: I rather like NAMELIST, been using it for many years.

Comment: I also like namelists very much, but to make the question less "opinion-based", it might be useful to focus on what features (or vendor extensions) of namelists are (were) not portable among compilers (which I also would like to know...)

Comment: I thought that namelists were essentially standard and portable feature since their inclusion in F90 onwards. While the resource refers to F90, I was not aware that their use had changed dramatically in more recent releases (I need to check up on those F2008 extensions).  I was basically wondering what aspect of them may be considered "poor design" and whether an alternative method was recommended by expert coders.

Comment: @AdrianTompkins I'm also very interested in why some people call namelists as "poor design" (because it is one of the most convenient features I use in Fortran...). The reason might be related to some troubles in old F77 compilers, I guess. You might get more useful info when you post the same question to some other forums (e.g., [compl.lang.fortran](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.fortran) ?)

Comment: FYI, this page might be interesting (about comparison among namelists, JSON, INI, XML, etc) http://degenerateconic.com/fortran-configuration-file-formats/ and related pages http://degenerateconic.com/tag/json/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no mention of namelist inefficiency and poor design whatsoever in the canonical book of Metcalf et al.: Modern Fortran Explained. https://books.google.com/books?id=V7UVDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA197#v=onepage&q=namelist%20I/O&f=false
To the contrary, I believe namelists -- especially with the added enhancements in Fortran 2003 and 2008 -- are quite useful and flexible method of data I/O.